# How can I use a button widget to grab an item from a listbox?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, listbox

When I press the "Take" button, it should grab the item from the Listbox and put that item into the "You are carrying" list as well as update the room and the Listbox.

I was thinking of making an updateWidget function that will clear the listbox after taking grabbable and will reload the listbox with new grabbables after moving to another room. It's just I don't know how to go about it.

```py
from tkinter import *

# the room class
# ...

# the game class
# inherits from the Frame class of Tkinter

    def createWidgets(self):
        # create the "Take" button
        self.takeButton = Button(self, text="Take", command=self.takeItem, width=10, height=2, font=("Arial", 16))
        self.takeButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        # create a frame to hold the label and listbox
        itemsFrame = Frame(self)
        itemsFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        # create the label and listbox widgets
        titleLabel = Label(itemsFrame, text="Grabbable Items", font=("Arial", 18))
        titleLabel.pack()
        self.itemListbox = Listbox(itemsFrame, font=("Arial", 14))
        self.itemListbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        # add items to the listbox
        for item in self.currentRoom.grabbables:
            self.itemListbox.insert(END, item)

    # function that will be called when the "Take" button is clicked
    def takeItem(self):
        # get the currently selected item from the listbox
        selected = self.itemListbox.curselection()
        if len(selected) == 0:
            return 
        item = self.itemListbox.get(selected[0])

        # remove the item from the room and add it to the player's inventory
        if item in self.currentRoom.grabbables:
            self.currentRoom.delGrabbable(item)
            self.inventory.append(item)


    # plays the game
    def play(self):
        # add the rooms to the game
        self.createRooms()
        # configure the GUI
        self.setupGUI()
        # set the current room
        self.setRoomImage()
        # set the current status
        self.setStatus("")

    # processes the player's input
    def process(self, event):
        # grab the player's input from the input at the bottom of the GUI
        action = Game.player_input.get()
        # set the user's input to lowercase to make it easier to compare the verb and noun to known values
        action = action.lower()
        # set a default response
        response = "I don't understand. Try verb noun. Valid verbs are go, look, and take"
        
        # exit the game if the player wants to leave (supports quit, exit, and bye)
        if (action == "quit" or action == "exit" or action == "bye" or action == "sionara!"):
            exit(0)
        
        # if the player is dead if goes/went south from room 4
        if (Game.currentRoom == None):
            # clear the player's input
            Game.player_input.delete(0, END)
            return
        
        # split the user input into words (words are separated by spaces) and store the words in a list
        words = action.split()
        
        # the game only understands two word inputs
        if (len(words) == 2):
            # isolate the verb and noun
            verb = words[0]
            noun = words[1]
            
            # the verb is: go
            if (verb == "go"):
                # set a default response
                response = "Invalid exit."
                # check for valid exits in the current room
                if (noun in Game.currentRoom.exits):
                    # if one is found, change the current room to the one that is associated with the specified exit
                    Game.currentRoom = Game.currentRoom.exits[noun]
                    # set the response (success)
                    response = "Room changed."
            
            # the verb is: look
            elif (verb == "look"):
                # set a default response
                response = "I don't see that item."
                # check for valid items in the current room
                if (noun in Game.currentRoom.items):
                    # if one is found, set the response to the item's description
                    response = Game.currentRoom.items[noun]
            
            # the verb is: take
            elif (verb == "take"):
                # set a default response
                response = "I don't see that item."
                # check for valid grabbable items in the current room
                for grabbable in Game.currentRoom.grabbables:
                    # a valid grabbable item is found
                    if (noun == grabbable):
                        # add the grabbable item to the player's inventory
                        Game.inventory.append(grabbable)
                        # remove the grabbable item from the room
                        Game.currentRoom.delGrabbable(grabbable)
                        # set the response (success)
                        response = "Item grabbed."
                        # no need to check any more grabbable items
                        break
            
        # display the response on the right of the GUI
        # display the room's image on the left of the GUI
        # clear the player's input
        self.setStatus(response)
        self.setRoomImage()
        Game.player_input.delete(0, END)
```

Comment: Please try to remove as much of the code as possible. The [mcve] needs to be a small as possible. For example, do we really need nearly a dozen property definitions and four "rooms" to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the difficulty when you try to write the `updateWidget()` function? Don't know how to clear a listbox?

Answer (score 0):

This code will handle "take" actions directly in the process function and display the available items and the player's inventory in the status area. The player can type "Take [item]" to grab an item, and the game will update the room and the displayed items accordingly.

```
from tkinter import *

# the room class
# ...

# the game class
# inherits from the Frame class of Tkinter

    # Remove createWidgets function

    # Remove takeItem function

    # plays the game
    def play(self):
        # add the rooms to the game
        self.createRooms()
        # configure the GUI
        self.setupGUI()
        # set the current room
        self.setRoomImage()
        # set the current status
        self.setStatus("")

    # processes the player's input
    def process(self, event):

        # the verb is: take
        elif (verb == "take"):
            # set a default response
            response = "I don't see that item."
            # check for valid grabbable items in the current room
            for grabbable in Game.currentRoom.grabbables:
                # a valid grabbable item is found
                if (noun == grabbable):
                    # add the grabbable item to the player's inventory
                    Game.inventory.append(grabbable)
                    # remove the grabbable item from the room
                    Game.currentRoom.delGrabbable(grabbable)
                    # set the response (success)
                    response = "Item grabbed: {}.\nYou are carrying: {}".format(grabbable, ', '.join(Game.inventory))
                    # no need to check any more grabbable items
                    break
            else:
                response = "Available items in the room: {}".format(', '.join(Game.currentRoom.grabbables))

        #rest of the function
```

Comment: So it might've been confusing, but the question I was asking is how make an updateWidget function that will clear listbox after taking grabbable and update it with the different grabbable as it goes to another room

Comment: inside of the function Clear the ListBox by deleting all its elements and Repopulate the ListBox with the new grabbables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
from tkinter import *


    def createWidgets(self):

        # create the label and listbox widgets

        # call the updateWidget function to populate the ListBox initially
        self.updateWidget()

    def updateWidget(self):
        # clear the ListBox
        self.itemListbox.delete(0, END)

        # add items to the ListBox
        for item in self.currentRoom.grabbables:
            self.itemListbox.insert(END, item)

    def takeItem(self):
        # remove the item from the room and add it to the player's inventory
        if item in self.currentRoom.grabbables:
            self.currentRoom.delGrabbable(item)
            self.inventory.append(item)

        # call the updateWidget function to update the ListBox after taking an item
        self.updateWidget()

    # plays the game
    def play(self):
        # set the current room
        self.setRoomImage()
        # set the current status
        self.setStatus("")

    # processes the player's input
    def process(self, event):
        # the verb is: go
        if (verb == "go"):
            # if one is found, change the current room to the one that is associated with the specified exit
            Game.currentRoom = Game.currentRoom.exits[noun]
            # set the response (success)
            response = "Room changed."
            
            # call the updateWidget function to update the ListBox when changing the room
            self.updateWidget()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?